# A MariaDB stored procedure parameter checking for a table is being interpreted as a table field

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I've got a Drupal database (MariaDB 10.4.17), and I'm trying to replace a string in a field only if:

1. The target table exists; and
2. One of the field values within contains a specific value

However when I run this, it throws the error `Unknown column 'my_table' in 'field list'`, which from what I've read suggests it is looking within a table for a *field* with that name and can't find it.

Why is this happening, and how can I make the code in the `THEN` block execute on a table only if it exists?

```sql
USE myDatabase;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE replaceLinks(
    tableName VARCHAR(255),
    fieldValue VARCHAR(255),
    fieldFormat VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM tableName
    ) THEN
        UPDATE tableName
        SET fieldValue = REPLACE(
                fieldValue,
                'TARGET_STR',
                'REPLACE_STR'
            )
        WHERE fieldFormat = 'html'
    END IF
END

DELIMITER ;

CALL replaceLinks(
    my_table field_value field_format
);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried with @danblack's answer, and still get the same error whether the table name I pass existed or not:
`Unknown column 'my_table' in 'field list'`.

It looks like there was 2 issues at work:

1. I was trying to use procedure parameters as variables for field names, as Dan noted; and
2. I was also passing the parameters without quotes despite them being strings, so they were not interpreted as such.

This now works exactly as intended:

```
USE myDatabase;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE replaceLinks(
        tableName VARCHAR(255),
        fieldValue VARCHAR(255),
        fieldFormat VARCHAR(255)
    ) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1146 SELECT 1;
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1054 SELECT 1;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT(
            'UPDATE ',
            tableName,
            ' SET ',
            fieldValue,
            ' = REPLACE(',
            fieldValue,
            ',\'TARGET_STR\', \'REPLACE_STR\') WHERE ',
            fieldFormat,
            ' = \'html\''
        );
    END
$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL replaceLinks(
        'my_table', 'field_value', 'field_format'
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procedure arguments cannot be used as variables SQL syntax for field names.

What you can do is using the magic of [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) to construct a query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE replaceLinks(tableName VARCHAR(255),
  fieldValue VARCHAR(255),
  fieldFormat VARCHAR(255) )
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('UPDATE ',
  tableName,
  ' SET ',
  fieldValue,
  ' = REPLACE(',
  fieldValue,
  ',\'TARGET_STR\', \'REPLACE_STR\') WHERE ',
  fieldFormat,
  ' = \'html\'');
```

To handle the not found use the [DECLARE HANDLER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/declare-handler/).

```
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1146 SELECT 1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ....;
END$$
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I still get validation errors though: 

`DELIMITER $$ 

BEGIN DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1051 SELECT 1;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE....;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;

CALL replaceLinks(param1 param2 param3);`

Error "near 'DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1051 SELECT 1; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CALL replac...' at line 2"

Comment: that was the body of the procedure so still needs a `CREATE PROCEDURE ..... fieldFormat VARCHAR(255)` before `BEGIN`.

Comment: Thanks @danblack, it took a while to figure out the syntax as I'm an SQL newbie - I've updated my question with a separate issue that was compounding the problem and slowed my debugging.